# Ionic Capacitor WebView: Cookies from root domain not accepted

Tags: ionic-framework, cookies, webview, capacitor

I'm trying to build an app with Ionic Capacitor. The app should use cookie for user to login. Let's say the server is `example.com` and the app in Capacitor WebView is hosted under `localhost` or `myapp.example.com` (by changing 'server --> hostname' in `capacitor.config.json`).
The problem is, when I fired a xhr-request from the app to the server, the `Set-Cookie` header in the response is not accepted. Here is an example of request and response:

**Request:**

```
Host: example.com
Origin: https://myapp.example.com
Referer: https://myapp.example.com/
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: a=something; Domain=example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
```

How can I get the cookie accepted in WebView? What headers should actually be set (Access-Control-Allow-*, Set-Cookie, etc.)? Is there any other special settings in the xhr-request what I am missing?

Comment: The following comment on GitHub might be of use to you: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1373#issuecomment-707822708

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments we found the solution of the problem:

1. on the server-side we need to response the preflight-request (OPTIONS) with these headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true (!important)
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (exact origin from request)
Access-COntrol-Allow-Methods: (allowed Methods)
Access-COntrol-Allow-Headers: (allowed header names)
```

2. on the client-side we need to set `withCredentials` of http-requests to true. In Angular we can simplely add the option `withCredentials` to all requests in an interceptor.

Then the `Set-Cookie` header works in client WebView. Don't forget to set `Domain` attribute in this header. e.g.

```
Set-Cookie: a=something; Domain=example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
```

Comment: after closing the app, cookie is not saved

Comment: @Meilech maybe the webview clears the cookie automatically after closing the app?

Comment: @Meir If `Expires` or `Max-Age` is not specified, it becomes a session cookie and will not last across sessions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie